# I'm not able to run Java program in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, input, user-input, inputstream

I have written a program that takes input from the input stream but I don't know how to proceed when the program is waiting for input? screenshot added:

[image: link to screenshot]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It is asking you, you simply need to type and press Enter

Comment: you need to use terminal for this code

Answer (score 0):

There is just one line missing, you need to close the Scanner before you can reach your last System.out.println.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        in.close(); //This one is important
        System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Then you click into the console and type in your first int --> press Enter and the same for the second int

Comment: after completion of my code i have clicked on run then its not asking me user input for example enter two numbers:  7  here its not asking only when i click at the place of 7 its asking

Answer (score 0):

as can be seen in your screenshot, your program runs and waits for your input, your IDE terminal is printing: "Enter two numbers:" and now is waiting on input due to the next line in your code: `int num1 = in.nextInt();`. just click on your terminal and see if you can enter an input and click enter on your keyboard, that should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

u need to click on the console and enter param.

Comment: Hi! please go through [Answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve the quality of your answer!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).